# Returing from game to menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have some problem with my android studio game. I don't know how to return from game to menu. Here is code from activity. I coulnd't get any information from GamePanel for example boolean :

```
public class Game extends Activity {
private boolean state= false;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //turn off title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    // usually shows xml activity_game
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //going to game loop

            setContentView(new GamePanel(Game.this));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start your main menu activity with CLEAR TASK and NEW TASK flags

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

I assume you know how to start and activity. If you don't https://developer.android.com/guide/